# Is there a gremlin notation for highlight the search term in search results?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm setting a janusgraph with airroutes graphml file. How can I highlight the search term in search results ?

for this query;

```
g.V().has('city', textContainsPrefix('At')).valueMap(true,'city')
```

Janusgraph response is

```
==>{city=[Haa Dhaalu Atoll], id=1188040, label=airport}
==>{city=[Athens], id=57392, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atiu Island], id=950408, label=airport}
==>{city=[Ataq], id=991432, label=airport}
==>{city=[Attawapiskat], id=1253600, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atlantic City], id=266288, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atyrau], id=499816, label=airport}
==>{city=[Huvadhu Atoll], id=2298096, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atlanta], id=8392, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atqasuk], id=1020104, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atmautluak], id=749792, label=airport}
==>{city=[Kaukura Atoll], id=1224744, label=airport}
==>{city=[Huvadhu Atoll], id=2351208, label=airport}
==>{city=[Majuro Atoll], id=577640, label=airport}
==>{city=[Atoifi], id=1441896, label=airport}
==>{city=[Athens], id=917608, label=airport}
==>{city=[Ahe Atoll], id=1790056, label=airport}
```

I need like that response

```
==>{city=[Haa Dhaalu 'At'oll], id=1188040, label=airport}
==>{city=['At'hens], id=57392, label=airport}
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any graph that supports these sorts of indices that also then supports highlighted hit results. I think you would have to post-process the results from your query to do that unfortunately.